# Can earth be used for communication?

Tags: rf, ground

I've heard of those things that tesla was trying to do by sending power into the earth using a 1 conductor transmission technique. Can the earth be used to send modulated signals of voice to be recieved somewhere else on earth like under the sea in a submarine?

Comment: For transmitting, microphone input, impedance match an audio amplifier output to rods inserted into the earth. When receiving, match that rod impedance to the input impedance, speaker for output. It will work like an intercom, but with party lines. I don't know about Tesla.

Comment: What are party lines?

Comment: Like a crystal radio, everyone using that technique can hear each other. Few know, so it should be no problem.

Comment: And I don't think there would be that many people in my area (any) doing that type of transmitting. In the mountains, and there aren't too many experimenters or people who like to mess around with stuff in my area

Comment: [yahoo] (http://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/2N1150_Down/conversations/topics/324) 
http://journal.borderlands.com/1997/an-introduction-to-the-mysteries-of-ground-radio/

Comment: You may need to use an Opamp as a preamp, for its large voltage gain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know about Tesla experiment, but the purpose you want is achieved by using Long Waves. Expecialy VLF, Very Low Frequency, with a wave length of 10-100 Km can literally follow the Earth curvature an penetrating the sea too at around 100 m depth. I'm not aware on any communication technique penetrating the Earth. An interesting thing to notice is that reducing the frequency also reduce the available bandwidth to modulate: some CW strategy are needed to send information other than plain modulation.

Comment: See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremely_low_frequency